# what is the logic to represent sub items from a box in an stock(Warehouse) database?

Tags: mysql, sql

For ex.: The process of buy a rice bag of 100 kg, give one entry for the completely bag, and then give out 20 or 30 kilogram of that bag. How to achieve it in the stock database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure can be different based on the behaviour of your application. There is no absolute way. But, I give you an example and you can find an idea:

inventory table:

```
id
date
merchandise_id
amount (negative for exit and positive for entry)
inventory_id (this is null for entry and includes the id of entry for exits)
```

Sample data:

```
id  |     date     |  merchandise_id  |  amount  |  inventory_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  2016-06-01  |        32        |   100    |      NULL
2   |  2016-06-03  |        32        |   -20    |      1
3   |  2016-06-04  |        32        |   -30    |      1
```